# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor: Is it possible to have C# code blocks without @if or @foreach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I havent really found a solution seaching through SO.

...and suspect I should really do this in the Model...

but is it possible to have C# code blocks where adhoc code can be added eg:

```
@int daysLeft = CurrentTenant.TrialExpiryDate.Subtract(DateTimeOffset.Now).Days
@if (daysLeft <= 0) {
{
   <text>
   Trial period completed  
   </text>
}
else
{
   <text>
   You have @daysLeft days left of you trial
   </text>
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure it is:

```
@{
    var one = 1;
    var two = one + one;
}
```

Phil Haack has a pretty popular [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) summing up Razor syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I have converted 99% of an app to Razor and didnt realise I could do this. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can create [functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2010/07/30/using-functions-in-an-asp-net-page-with-razor-syntax.aspx) in razor which is what I believe you are looking for.

[Another explanation](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-6-function-blocks.html).

Comment: Thanks, didnt know about functions

Answer (score 3):

You could also use templated razor delagates. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx

Something like this should work.

```
public static class RazorExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult TrialMessage(this int days,
      Func<T, HelperResult> template)
    {
        return new HelperResult(writer =>
        {
            if (days <=0)
                template("Trial period completed").WriteTo(writer);
            else
                template("You have " + days  + " days left of you trial").WriteTo(writer);
        });
    }
}
```

In the view use:

```
@int daysLeft = CurrentTenant.TrialExpiryDate.Subtract(DateTimeOffset.Now).Days
@daysLeft.TrialMessage(@<text>@item@</text>)
```